# Generate a flag column if the Status is Unchanged for 2 hours

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe with columns Time, Unique_ID and Status. For each Unique ID, if the status remains CLOSED for more than 2 hours, I need to generate a flag column with value 'True' in it, otherwise 'False'. I tried pivoting the table but I didn't feel that it is the right solution. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Could you share data to work on and not image :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dummy['Flag'] = 'FALSE'
y=0
while y < len(dummy):
    dummy['Flag'].iloc[y] = ((datetime.datetime.now()-dummy['Time'].iloc[y]) > datetime.timedelta(hours=2)) if dummy['Status'].iloc[y] == 'CLOSED' else 'FALSE'
    y=y+1
```

I'm just initiating a column with FALSE text then looping through Dataframe and checking for each row and updating status. Not the best way though but it's quiet easy to understand and edit. Hope it helps.!

I'll share more pythonic way if you need but I guess this will do :)